# SPFx Extensions - popup “loading debug scripts” does not appear in a list

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, spfx-extensions

I built the application as described in this [tutorial](https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-fx-extensions/tree/master/samples/js-command-clone)

The popup appears on the site, but does not appear in the list of this site.

Did anyone have a problem of this type?

This path works:
`/sites/mySite?loadSPFX=true&debugManifestsFile=https://localhost:4321/temp/manifests.js&customActions={%22bf6645bd-42e4-4a30-aad7-6ff12d61fa1f%22:{%22location% 22: 22ClientSideExtension.ListViewCommandSet% 22%}}`

This path does not work:
`/sites/mySite/Lists/myList/AllItems.aspx?loadSPFX=true&debugManifestsFile=https://localhost:4321/temp/manifests.js&customActions={%22bf6645bd-42e4-4a30-aad7- 6ff12d61fa1f 22% {% 22location 22%: 22% 22ClientSideExtension.ListViewCommandSet%}}`

The site and list have a modern appearance.

Comment: did you create a new extension using yeoman or cloned it from Git repository ?